# Did I do this proof right?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

I am not sure if I did the proof right, so I wanted to see how most of you did this. I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $x, y \in \mathbb N$  be relatively prime. If $xy$ is a perfect square, prove that $x$ and $y$ must be both perfect squares.

Here is my proof:

If $x$ and $y$ are both relatively prime, then if a $p_i | x$ then $p_i$ does not divide $y$ and vice versa. Then by FTA, $xy = p_{i_0}p_{i_1} ...$ and this is the only unique factorization of $xy$.Then if $xy = n^2$ for some number n, then $xy = p_{g_0}^2p_{g_1}^2...$ So if $p_{l} | xy$ then $p_l^2 | x $ or $y$ Therefore both x and y are a product of primes squared. Therefore both x and y are perfect squares.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your work so that we can assess whether your proof is correct.

Comment: Here, I showed my own work.

Comment: This looks more or less correct. I think you just need to argue that there aren't any single prime powers in $x$ or $y$ (just a slight modification of what you've already argued).

Comment: Good for you, @SalmonKiller. Thanks for responding to comments. Don't fret about showing your work (now or in the future), especially when you're unsure it's correct. I personally have always been a bit "bashful" of submitting work about which I didn't feel entirely correct. At worst, you made an error here or there. But we all make errors (and there's no shame in that); sometimes we learn best by failing the first, or second (or third) attempt. I think your proof shows that you are certainly on the right track!

Comment: The fact that there is a subtle error in the proof makes this an _excellent_ question. To do correct math, it is useful to recognize errors and avoid them, and a good way to learn to recognize errors is to let someone point them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof does not suffice. At the end, your conclusion that if a prime $p|xy$, then $p^2|x$ or $p^2|y$ is correct, but it doesn't exclude, for instance, that $p^3|y$ but $p^4\not| y$, in which case $y$ wouldn't be square.

However, you're going in the right direction. Notice that we can write
$$x=p_1p_2p_3\ldots p_i$$
for some primes $p_i$ and
$$y=q_1q_2q_3\ldots q_j$$
for some primes $q_j$ distinct from any $p_i$. This means that
$$xy=p_1p_2p_3\ldots p_i q_1 q_2 q_3\ldots q_j$$
and, by hypothesis that $xy$ is square, each prime must appear an even number of times - but since any given prime can only appear in either the sequence $p$ or in $q$, it follows that each prime dividing $xy$ appears an even number of times in the sequence $p$ or $q$, implying further than any prime dividing $x$ appears an even number of times in $p$ and any prime dividing $y$ appears an even number of times in $q$. Thus, $x$ and $y$ must be square.

This is essentially the same as your proof, just without appealing to divisibility conditions at the end, and replacing anything to do with primes appearing twice with them appearing an even number of times.

Comment: Another way to fix the argument might be, after finding that $p^2\mid y$, let $y'=y/p^2$ and repeat the procedure with $x$ and $y'$. Since the original $x$ and $y$ had each a finite number of prime factors, eventually you will remove all of them. Then for each time you extracted $p^2$ from $y$ you have one factor of $p$ in $\sqrt y$. Of course this is just a different way of saying that each prime occurs an even number of times.

Answer (score 1):

For each prime $p$, let $\nu_p(x)$ denote the largest power of $p$ that divides $x$. Note that for any $x,y$, we have that $\nu_p(xy)=\nu_p(x)+\nu_p(y)$. Saying that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime means that for each prime $p$, $\nu_p(xy)$ is either $0$ or one of $\nu_p(x)$, $\nu_p(y)$, indeed: for example, if $p$ divides $x$, then it cannot divide $y$, so $\nu_p(xy)=\nu_p(x)$.

By hypothesis $\nu_p(xy)$ is even for each prime $p$, so the above implies that for each prime $p$, $\nu_p(x)$ and $\nu_p(y)$ are even, since they equal $\nu_p(xy)$.

In fact, if $x,y$ are coprime, $\nu_p(xy)=\nu_p(x)+\nu_p(y)=\max(\nu_p(x),\nu_p(y))$ for each prime $p$. Saying $x,y$ are squares is the same as saying $\nu_p$ is even for each prime $p$, for both $y$ and $x$.